# magento 2 error : while Compiling getting following error

Tags: magento2, error

**Errors during compilation:**

```
Magento\Ccavenuepay\Block\Transparent\Form
    Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Payment\Model\Config. Actual type: \Magento\Ccavenuepay\Model\Config; 
    File:
    /home/bhushankamble90/public_html/magento2/app/code/Magento/Ccavenuepay/Block/Transparent/Form.php

    Magento\Ccavenuepay\Helper\Backend\Data

    Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory. Actual type: \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface; File:
    /home/bhushankamble90/public_html/magento2/app/code/Magento/Ccavenuepay/Helper/Backend/Data.php

    Magento\Ccavenuepay\Controller\Ccavenuepay\Place
    Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session. Actual type: \Magento\Framework\Registry; File:
    /home/bhushankamble90/public_html/magento2/app/code/Magento/Ccavenuepay/Controller/Ccavenuepay/Place.php

    Total Errors Count: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please follow below steps to remove these errors.

```
app/code/Magento/Ccavenuepay/Block/Transparent/Form.php
```

Change

```
use Magento\Ccavenuepay\Model\Config;
```

with

```
use Magento\Payment\Model\Config;
```

> app/code/Magento/Ccavenuepay/Helper/Backend/Data.php

Change Constructor with below code:**

```
   public function __construct(
         \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
        \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Factory $paymentMethodFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $appEmulation,
        \Magento\Payment\Model\Config $paymentConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial $initialConfig,
        \Magento\Ccavenuepay\Model\Cbdom_main $Cbdom_main 
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $layoutFactory, $paymentMethodFactory, $appEmulation, $paymentConfig, $initialConfig, $Cbdom_main);
        $this->_urlBuilder = $backendUrl;
    }
```

> app/code/Magento/Ccavenuepay/Controller/Ccavenuepay/Place.php

and Change Constructor with below code:

```
public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $coreRegistry,
        DataFactory $dataFactory,
        CartManagementInterface $cartManagement,
        Onepage $onepageCheckout,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $csession,
        JsonHelper $jsonHelper,

        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
        \Magento\Ccavenuepay\Model\Ccavenuepay $ccavenuepay,
        \Magento\Ccavenuepay\Helper\Checkout $checkoutHelper,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger

    ) {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $this->logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $this->logger->addWriter($writer);
        $this->logger->info("Place extends Ccavenuepay=====");

        $this->eventManager = $context->getEventManager();
        $this->cartManagement = $cartManagement;
        $this->onepageCheckout = $onepageCheckout;
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $checkoutSession, $orderFactory, $ccavenuepay, $checkoutHelper, $logger);
    }
```